# ¿Es posible poder delimitar el numero de veces que se genere un numero aleatorio?

Tags: c#, random

Quería saber si existe la posibilidad de poner un numero de limite para que aparezca un mismo numero Random, lo que estoy haciendo es un juego de memoria (Memorama), y quiero que solamente aparezca la carta 1, dos veces y asi sucesivamente con todas las cartas, pero no quiero que aparezca tres veces ya que entonces no seguiría la lógica del juego.
Un pequeño ejemplo:

### Aqui genero el numero de imagen de la carta 1

```
int numeroimagen = rnd.Next(0, 2);
int dato_aleatorio1;
dato_aleatorio1 = numeroimagen;
```

### Aqui genero el numero de imagen de la carta 2

```
int numeroimagen = rnd.Next(0, 2);
int dato_aleatorio2;
dato_aleatorio2 = numeroimagen;
PB1.Image = ImageList1.Images[dato_aleatorio2];
```

### Aqui genero el numero de imagen de la carta 3

```
int numeroimagen = rnd.Next(0, 2);
int dato_aleatorio3;
dato_aleatorio3 = numeroimagen;
PB1.Image = ImageList1.Images[dato_aleatorio3];
```

### Aqui genero el numero de imagen de la carta 4

```
int numeroimagen = rnd.Next(0, 2);
int dato_aleatorio4;
dato_aleatorio4 = numeroimagen;
PB1.Image = ImageList1.Images[dato_aleatorio4];
```

Quisiera el numero 1 generado aleatoriamente solo se repitiera 2 veces y no más, y así con el numero 2.
Espero puedan ayudarme :)

Comment: Random es random (en realidad es pseudoaleatorio, hay una linda respuesta en el sitio respecto a eso). No, no podes decirle que excluya valores.. tenes que ir contandolos y excluyendolos vos...

Comment: Los pseudoaleatorios que saques con distribución uniforme, tienen todos la misma probabilidad... Te queda el llevar un array de los que han salido dos veces y volver a calcular hasta que salga uno que no esté en el array. Total, los ciclos de CPU son baratos hoy día.

Comment: Creo que deberías repasar un poco la lógica de tu código. No veo el porqué debas generar 2 veces el mismo número, tampoco veo la necesidad de generar aleatoriamente números para la secuencia del juego. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que buscas no la obtendrás forzando el motor de números pseudo-aleatorios si no con algorítmica.

La mejor aproximación es crear una lista con los resultados que quieres, por ejemplo:

```
var numeros = new List<int>{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
```

Y después mezclarla aleatoriamente:

```
for (var elementos = numeros.Count - 1; elementos > 1; --elementos)
{
    int indice = rand.Next(elementos + 1);
    int valor = numeros[indice];
    numeros[indice] = numeros[elementos];
    numeros[elementos] = valor;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZGxTsQwDIbn5Ck8toJWKoyFW25gORCCgeF0Q5TzlUitIyVpAZ367MVpe72C5CG2f//@rGifaetwGFpvqIL3Hx@wKeU6y7e2rlEHY8nnT0jojC6l1LXyHl6drZxq5FkKH1QwGjprjvCsDCU@OHbZH0C5yqdSsEZ0ygG1DTrr4REIv2BnfHgwFDbn4hY47sa45@jLecApOs7qN37aJkkZQIiTdZBEAdbYIIXJc3Jn6pYCZFCUq/Ymplm2FJhqxBIMAIaORiNbxH35C36H5Dp5A0VaXpSdqnn1sms/TR7G/r/aSrWY/RVey6wdnWO7nw9EpT@nIzsGvHhFbrHlD7E15h/OBNwZwqSLiL3sh@EX)</kbd>.